# Angular 2 Nested Routes using @Routes

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-routing

I'm trying to do something seemingly simple. I have the following defined:

```
@Routes([
    { path: '/stores', component: StoresComponent },
    { path: '/stores/new', component: StoresCreateComponent}
])
```

When I navigate to `/stores` I display a list of existing stores. I have a link on that page to navigate to a screen to create a new store. However, when I navigate to `/stores/new`, I get the following:

```
browser_adapter.ts:78Error: Uncaught (in promise): Component 'StoresComponent' does not have route configuration
```

I'm pretty new to Angular so I'm not entirely sure what I need to do in order to get a route like that working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order routes so that more specific ones come first and less specific ones last. That's a current limitation of the RC.1 router.

```
@Routes([
    { path: '/stores/new', component: StoresCreateComponent}
    { path: '/stores', component: StoresComponent },
])
```

Comment: Well, that did the trick. Is there anything officially documented as to this limitation and what the plan is for it in the future?

Comment: This will definitely be fixed. The RC.1 router has currently several limitations. It was a bit hasty to include a new router just before ng-conf where they were eager to announce RC. Now they have some tasks in the backlog to get things completed. Hard to tell when exactly this will be fixed but I think it has high prio.

Comment: That the order of routes matters is actually by design and won't change.